# Firebase UI - How to synchronize a ListView with complex data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am writing an app for Android, in which there are events and users.

An event has many users, and an user has many events.

So I structured my database like this:

```
- events
    - <event_id>
        - ...
        - users
            - <user_id1>
            - <user_id2>
            - ...
- users
   - <user_id1>
        - <user_detail1>
        - <user_detail2>
        - ...
   - <user_id2>
        - <user_detail1>
        - <user_detail2>
        - ...
```

Now, I have an Activity with a ListView, and I successfully managed to show a list of all the events with FirebaseUI using a FirebaseListAdapter.

I have a second Activity in which I want to show event details, with another ListView showing the list of users for that event.

My question is: if I use a FirebaseListAdapter I can only show the user_id, how can I retrieve user details an show them in the ListView?

**EDIT**

To be more precise, I want the list of the users of a specific event to be linked to a ListView. I want to use a FirebaseListAdapter for that, so my code looks like this at the moment:

```
fireAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
                this,
                String.class,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mRootRef.child("events").child("users") //here I have all user_id that I want to retrieve details for
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {
                //the string "model" will now have a user_id
                TextView userName = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1); //I want to populate this field

                String usernameString;

                //How do I get to retrieve the username from user_id into this variable?

                userName.setText(usernameString);
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the user details, you can attach a listener to the user-id. The listener will be automatically called `onChildAdded()` or `onChildChanged()` methods. For your case, since you want the information only for the first time, you can retrieve all values with the snapshot that is returned in the function with the method `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` and to get the exact values use the function `dataSnapShot.child('blah-blah').value()`

For the complete reference check out the [Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data).

Your code might look something like this

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.child('users').child('user_id1').setChildListener(ListenerName);
```

Comment: Ok so thanks to your reply I found out that it is possible to attach a listener inside the poplateView function of FirebaseListAdapter, and works like a charm :) Many thanks